# python3 dictionary get.key - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a problem which my novice knowledge cannot solve.
I'm trying to copy some python-2.x code (which is working) to python-3.x. Now it gives me an error.
Here's a snippet of the code:

```
def littleUglyDataCollectionInTheSourceCode():
a = {
  'Aabenraa':   [842.86917819535, 25.58264089252],
  'Aalborg':    [706.92644963185, 27.22746146366],
  'Aarhus': [696.60346488317, 25.67540525994],
  'Albertslund':    [632.49007681987, 27.70499807418],
  'Allerød':    [674.10474259426, 27.91964123274],
  'Assens': [697.02257492453, 25.83386400960],
  'Ballerup':   [647.05121493736, 27.72466920284],
  'Billund':    [906.63431520239, 26.23136823557],
  'Bornholm':   [696.05765684503, 28.98396327957],
  'Brøndby':    [644.89390717471, 28.18974127413],
  }
  return a
```

and:

```
def calcComponent(data):
# Todo: implement inteface to set these values by
# the corresponding 'Kommune'
T = float(data.period)
k = 1.1
rH = 1.0

# import with s/\([^\s-].*?\)\t\([0-9.]*\)$/'\1':'\2',/
myDict = littleUglyDataCollectionInTheSourceCode();
#if data.kommune in myDict:
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/unicode/
key = data.kommune.encode("utf-8")
rd = myDict.get(key.strip(), 0)
laP = float(rd[0]) # average precipitation
midV = float(rd[1]) # Middelværdi Klimagrid
print(("lap " + str(laP)))
print(("mid V" + str(midV)))
```

It gives the error:

```
line 14, in calcComponent
laP = float(rd[0]) # average precipitation
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried different approaches and read dozens of aticles with no luck. Being a novice it is like tumbling in the dark.

Comment: what is `data` or what's `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `myDict` is a dictionary with strings as keys and lists as values.

```
key = data.kommune.encode("utf-8")
```

will be a bytes object, so there can't ever be any corresponding value for that key in the dictionary. This worked in python2 where automatic conversion was performed, but not anymore in python3, you need to use the correct type for lookups.

```
rd = myDict.get(key.strip(), 0)
```

will always return the integer `0`, which means that `rd[0]` can not work because integers are not indexable, as the error message tells you.

Generally the default value in a `get()` call should be compatible with what is returned in all other cases. Returning `0` as default where all non-default cases return lists can only lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `0` as a default value for `rd`, whereas the values in the dict are lists, so if the key is not found, `rd[0]` or `rd[1]` will fail. Instead, use a list or tuple as default, then it should work.

```
rd = myDict.get(key.strip(), [0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

And that is why googling the TypeError text didn't lead me to a solution, as my problem were twofold. I forgot about the integrated encoding in Python3.
I changed:

```
key = data.kommune.encode("utf-8")
rd = myDict.get(key.strip(), 0)
```

to:

```
key = data.kommune
rd = myDict.get(key.strip(), [0, 0])
```

And now it works:-)